# how do I center the full page?

Tags: html, css, centering

How do I center the full page ? 
I tried adding my object.css.css file:

```
#content {
  width: 700px ;
  margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
```

}

But that didnt help. I also tried:

```
.field
{
  margin:auto;
  width:70%;

}
```

But that didn't include `h1` elements

Thanks.
EDIT: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeFSt.jpg

Comment: what does your page look like?  I am assuming you have a div wrapping your content like `<div id='content'></div>`

Comment: Can you please show us some of the ouptput HTML?  You don't need to show the entire page, but a summary of the code would be helpful.  Or post it all in a jsfiddle.

Comment: That's not going to be enough to go on.  Link to the page?  Or paste the html and css into a jsfiddle.net page.

Comment: @perry Still not enough. See http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a Ruby on Rails question as much as it is an HTML/CSS question. Your stylesheet should contain something like:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
```

And of course, whatever other content your layout contains can have other effects.

Answer (score 1):

To center elements on the page you use `margin:0 auto;` and set a width but to center text within an element you would use `text-align:center;`

Answer (score 1):

To center content we first wrap the page in a div, then center the #content within that wrapper div.

your css would look like:

```
 #wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
 }
 #content {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 700px;
 }
```

your html would look like:

```
 <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="content">
        Content Stuffs
     </div>
 </div>
```