# Center an iframe horizontally

Tags: html, css, centering

This piece of code effectively centers the iframes but on their **left** edge not their center.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Videos</title>
    <style>
        div.center {
            width: 200px;
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background: lightblue">
    <div class="center">
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/dgZ-K87NcwQ"></iframe>
        <p />
        <iframe src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/xoy7jd"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

I've seen these questions :

- [How to center an iframe horizontally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366957/how-to-center-an-iframe-horizontally)
- [how do I center the full page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590140/how-do-i-center-the-full-page)
- [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-a-div-in-a-div-horizontally)
- [How to center an iframe horizontally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366957/how-to-center-an-iframe-horizontally)

Unfortunately none worked for me.

How would one *really* center these on the screen ?

Comment: In HTML, don't write `<p />`. It doesn't do what you think it does. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmss8/). You could do it in XHTML, but it would be strongly advised against. Not in HTML though. And besides, you shouldn't use paragraphs for vertical spacing.

Comment: Right, should I use <br/> instead ?

Comment: No. Give the iframes `display:block` and then you can put margins on them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is that your iframes are wider than 200px (the fixed width you've defined for their centered containing div). This will cause their excess width to spill over the right boundry of the div.

Depending on the full structure of your site try putting the auto margin directly on the iframes.

```
div.center iframe{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NvfKu/

Comment: can simplify to ->  display: block; margin: 0 auto;